# What's a good shortcut to immediately and abruptly terminate the process that uses the most memory?

Tags: windows-10

I have looked around and every answer stops short of describing how to just kill the process. Even if it's still responsive and nothing is wrong with it. I know that I will lose my data, point is that I need to kill the program.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To get out of the program quickly.

Comment: There is no shortcut for this.

Comment: The program that uses most memory might be an important one that you shouldn't stop.

Comment: Is there a criteria using /taskkill for using 1MB or above of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `taskkill` with the `MEMUSAGE` filter. This kills tasks if their memory usage is a certain number. Usage:

```bat
taskkill /t /f /fi "MEMUSAGE gt <X amount of kilobytes>"
```

This will kill processes taking more than x amounts of kilobytes of memory. In powershell, you can use `$ProcessList = Get-Process | Sort-Object -Descending WS` to list tasks in descending order from memory usage. You could kill the highest memory using task using:

```ps1
$PL = Get-Process | Sort-Object -Descending WS
$High = $PL[0] | select 'ID'
taskkill /t /f /pid $High
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can simply go to Task Manager, select the task, and click End Task. If it doesn't allow you to end the task, it's probably important and should not be killed.

Comment: the question is literally tagged windows-10

Comment: Oops! I didn't see that because I was on an iPhone SE which is very small. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the whole point is to avoid going to Task Manager in the first place.